$N_{1/2}$ why say discrete when can be continuous?
This is a quick question which is more to do with notation and less about mathematics. From a book on stochastic processes (reading it to supplement understanding of another paper in nuclear beta decay):

Let $(N_t)_{t\ge 0}$ be a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ with $0\lt T_1\lt T_2 < \ldots$ be the arrival times of $(N_t)_{t\ge 0}$.

It then goes on to ask the reader to calculate, for example, $P(N_4\le 2, N_1=1)$ and so on. But one part of the question asks you to compute $P(N_3= 2, N_1=2, N_{1/2}=0)$
The question surrounds the $\bf N_{1/2}$ term. I assume it means the number of events that have occurred by time $\frac T 2$? It caught me off guard because the author uses "discrete notation" to refer to the arrival times i.e., $T_n , n\in \mathbb{N}$ when it seemed (to me) the author could have written "$T\in\mathbb{R^+}$"?
Any pointers are appreciated.

I would say $N_{1/2}$ is number of points by time $1/2$.

The notation $N_t$ means the number of arrivals of the Poisson process by time $t$. It takes continuous inputs (this is why we write $t\geq 0$ in $(N_t)_{t\geq 0}$), but discrete outputs (we cannot have half an arrival).
On the other hand, $T_n$ means the arrival time of the $n$th arrival. It takes in discrete inputs (again, arrivals come in integer quantities), but gives continuous outputs, since the last arrival could arrive at any time.
The notation $T_n,n\in \mathbb{N}$ is not intended to mean that $T_n\in \mathbb{N}$, but rather that $n\in\mathbb{N}$ -- it only makes sense to talk the $n$th arrival time when $n$ is natural.
